# Reverse video generating with mencoder

Tags: mencoder

I'm currently using mencoder to generate a video file output of many pngs

```
mencoder 'mf://*.png' -mf type=png:fps=2 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=wmv2 -oac copy -o out.mpg")
```

This works fine, but i actually need the time reversed version. Sure it would be possible to rename the files so they are in the right order but isn't there another way to start with the higher values and stop with the lower ones?

Answer (score -1):

I might be late, bit for the record:

`ls -r *.png >> filelist.txt; mencoder "mf://@filelist.txt" -ovc lavc -o aegeespirit2.avi`